# Updating a property on one class from other classes while multithreading

Tags: c#, multithreading

I am using WPF and MVVM pattern, but that's not really relevant in this case. In my ViewModel `MainVM`, I have a property like this:

```
public int Posts {
    get { return this.posts; }
    set {
        this.posts = value;
        this.OnPropertyChanged(nameof(this.Posts));
    }
}
```

Through properties, I supply `MainVM` a list of `Foo`. (Actually, I want to supply it using the constructor, but I can't. Read below) And there is a start method on the `MainVM` which does as follows:

```
foreach(Foo foo in this.Foos){ // this.Foos is just a List<Foo>
    Task.Run(() => foo.Bar());
}
```

In the execution of `Foo.Bar` (There are lots of methods being called in `Bar`, so passing an `Action` to bar itself is not really feasible), it is supposed to update a value, and that value is `MainVM.Posts`. Passing `MainVM` to `Foo` is not an option. So I thought of passing an `Action` instead. So I wrote this Method in `MainVM`.

```
public void IncrementPosts()
{
    lock(this.whatever) 
    {
        this.Posts++;
    }
}
```

Then I made `Foo` take an `Action` in the constructor. So here's how the `Foos` are created and passed to `MainVM`.

```
var vm = new MainVM();

var foo1 = new Foo(vm.IncrementPosts);
var foo2 = new Foo(vm.IncrementPosts);

vm.Foos = new List<Foo>() {foo1, foo2};
```

Whilst this works, I feel that it looks ugly. First of all, `MainVM` **needs** a list of `Foo` to work properly. So it's supposed to be supplied to the constructor, right? But as a `Foo` needs an action which points to a method in `MainVM`, I can't do that. And all of this looks like a hack.

Is there a better way of doing this?

Comment: @Downvoter, it would be nice of you if you commented on this question why you feel it's should be downvoted. At least I would know what needs improvement then.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand, what are you want to do..

```
void Main()
{
    var vm = new MainVM(new FooFactory());
    Console.WriteLine(vm.Posts);
    vm.ExecuteFoo();
    Console.WriteLine(vm.Posts);    
}

public class Foo
{
    private Action _action;
    public Foo(Action action)
    {
        _action = action;
    }

    public void RunAction()
    {
        _action();
    }
}

public class FooFactory
{   
    public Foo[] CreateFoo(MainVM vm)
    {
        return new[] { new Foo(()=>vm.Posts++) };
    }
}

public class MainVM : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public MainVM(FooFactory factory)
    {
        _foos = factory.CreateFoo(this);
    }

    public void ExecuteFoo()
    {
        foreach(var foo in _foos)
        foo.RunAction();
    }

    private Foo[] _foos;

    private int posts;
    public int Posts
    {
        get { return this.posts; }
        set
        {
            this.posts = value;
            this.OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName]string propertyName = null)
    {       
        var local = PropertyChanged;
        if (local != null)
        {
            local(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: There's no lock around posts incrementation?

Comment: It's just sample, how you can pass foo creation to view model ctor. Lock is too expensive, if you want only increment, use interlocked class.

Comment: Yep. In case of interlocked you should use somth like that 
```
        public void IncreasePosts()
 {
  Interlocked.Add(ref posts, 1);
  OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Posts));
 }
```